# jQuery and PHP - Comet

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, comet, long-polling

I've searched Google a lot. In all the examples having `Comet` with `PHP` and `jQuery`. They are doing:

```
setTimeout(function(){ check_new_data_function() }, 5000); 

function check_new_data_function(){
    $.ajax{
    blah
    }
}
```

And yes, it's pretty simple to use Comet with checks in every 5 seconds. But this could not be called "COMET" at all, isn't the purpose of Comet to not loop our requests? and instead get the data which is ***Pushed*** from server?

[See this example.](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)
Or [another clip.](http://www.screenr.com/SNH)
They are all having a function which gets the data from another file with `$.ajax` requests by looping. But are they really `Long Polling/Comet`?

As far as I knew when we didn't want to put the server under many `$.ajax` request which are looped, we would use Comet, in Comet the data is gonna Pushed from server to the client browser, was I wrong?

Could someone make this idea clear for me?

Comment: Well, first come down. `:P` Browsers don't yet broadly support web sockets. So long polling is preferred. You do see libraries that incorporate web sockets, though, and use them if they are available.

Comment: @JaredFarrish is there any difference between Long Polling and Comet? and would you give some example on other libraries? how facebook and twitter are implementing their own Comet?

Comment: Comet is an interface through a socket; it's *push*, so comet means *it tells you when you have [whatever]*. Long polling is leaving a request open long enough to shorten the distance between the messenger and receiver, but the receiver (the client) has to initiate the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Can I Use**](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20sockets) on *Web Sockets - Working Draft*:

---

> Partial support refers to the websockets implementation using an older
>   version of the protocol and/or the implementation being disabled by
>   default (due to security issues with the older protocol). Microsoft is
>   currently experimenting with the technology.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nRwm.png

The technology just isn't there yet. Watch this [video from SymfonyLive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEWTPFzt2-E) if you want a better grasp on what the specs for HTTP and REST *mean*. It's interesting, and apparently Twitter goofed.

Also see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations

Comment: then how Facebook and Twitter are using their Comet? are they looping their requests? the answer would be definitely no if you asked me, because that would be a complete mess!

Comment: Some browsers support it, and so does iOS and most programming languages. I imagine that's why Facebook's app on the iPhone is a native app now, so they could abandon the web's stateless polling situation.

Comment: Facebook use HTTP long-polling. Whilst Comet techniques will be around for a while still WebSockets are the best solution for realtime bi-directional communication between a web client and a web server. More info on [Comet v WebSockets here](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2012/04/22/websockets-realise-comet-theyre-not-an-alternative.html)